# Visualization through CloudWatch Insights

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am logging automation results in CloudWatch logs. The format is like this:

```
(XXXX-XXXX) Endpoint request body after transformations: 
{
    "executionDetails": {
        "executionId": "uniqueExecutionId",
        "userName": "<userName>",
        "sourcePackage": "<testPackage>"
}
}
```

Now, I want to understand the number of unique users of our framework. How do I get that data through cloudwatch insights?

I tried the following query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /Endpoint request body after transformations:/
| parse @message "userName" as userName
| stats count(userName) as UniqueMessageCount by userName
| sort UniqueMessageCount desc
```

and this too:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /Endpoint request body after transformations:/
| parse @message "userName" as users
| stats count(users) as uniqueMessageCount by users
| sort uniqueUsers desc
```

But this doesn't seem to be giving the correct results. I found the following question, which seems to be similar what I am asking, but all the answers give incorrect results - [Count unique values in aws cloudwatch metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765601/count-unique-values-in-aws-cloudwatch-metric) .

I also need to log which user executed how many times. Can anyone help me with this?

Sharing an example of my data:

```
|":"John","sourcePackage":"<my package 1 >"}}| 1
|":"John","sourcePackage":"<my package 2 >"}}| 1
```

These 2 should be shown as :

```
|"John"| 2
```

Comment: What do you mean by - _this doesn't seem to be giving the correct results_? Your queries are already returning unique user records and their count. Can you add the expected result data?

Comment: I want the data in the format:
<alias> | <number of times this alias was found>

However - I am getting uniqueness for the whole thing`"userName": "<userName>, "sourcePackage": "<testPackage>"` if john is invoking a test case from 2 different packages - I want a single row with 2 as the count, instead I am getting 2 rows along with source package in the userName and 1 count for each of them. Hope that makes things clear!